# What healing spell did Cadderly cast on Ivan Bouldershoulder?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, dungeons-and-dragons, adnd-2e, content-identification

In the R.A. Salvatore books *Cleric Quintet*, Ivan Bouldershoulder was seriously injured. Cadderly put a ring of Regeneration on, then cast a spell that removed the wounds from Ivan and they appeared on Cadderly – but he healed from them quickly because of the ring.

Was that spell a Divine Clerical spell or part of the Song of Deneir?

I can't find it in my 3.5 books; perhaps it was 2e...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, this definitely wasn't from 3E or 3.5; the Cleric Quintet was published in the early '90s ('91-'94), at the height of the 2E era ('89-'99). It was republished in 2000 around the same time 3E came out, which may explain why you think it's newer.

Secondly, I wouldn't be so certain the author was sticking to strict AD&D rules. It's been a while since I read those books, but they definitely played fast and loose with both the rules and [setting material](https://www.reddit.com/r/Forgotten_Realms/comments/7gtt1e/ra_salvatore_not_bothering_to_adhere_to_forgotten/). After all, a story in which healing is trivially available because of a cleric being around makes some forms of drama a little too easy to resolve; same way a lot of D&D writers ignore the ability of their high-level wizards to teleport, because it makes it too easy to get from place to place at the last second.

All that said, **it's possible he was intentionally making use of the 2E *Life Drain* spell**. It's a 3rd level Priest spell that drains HP from a touched target (1d8 + 1/caster level) and allows the priest to heal themselves or someone else with the drained life. The rules on it are written a little weirdly (it's not clear to me if it's technically legal for the priest to drain *themselves* to heal another; it's definitely allowed to drain a friendly though), but I'm sure many DMs would allow it (there's no exploit in allowing the priest to injure themselves).

Comment: It may be moot considering the dates on the novel and the games, but for the record, 3.x usually gave clerics “pure” healing powers, that just healed. Powers that hurt yourself in exchange for healing another were given to other classes who weren't supposed to be “good at” healing, e.g. the psion’s *empathic transfer* and the wizard’s *healing touch*. I can’t be sure that the cleric didn’t get such an option, but none comes to mind unless you count preemptive options like *shield other*.

Comment: @KRyan: Agreed. 3.x introducing spontaneous *Cure* casting for most PC clerics made it largely pointless to even consider the use of a spell like *Life Drain* to drain from a friendly (evil clerics might need it sometimes I guess); why blow a 3rd level spell to get 1st level healing *and* harm a party member in the process, when you could just spontaneous cast *Cure Serious Wounds* and heal (on average) 9 more HP, ex nihilo, with no harm to the party? But yeah, Cleric Quintet was definitely 2E, and in 2E, you might burn all your cure spells and need to repurpose *Life Drain* to save the dying.